# how to access Azure .net core webiste files using powershell from my azure deploy pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a website in done with asp.net core and deploy with AzureDevOps, Host on a Azure webiste as well. On my deploy pipeline I added a powershell task to make changes to the web.config. please see image [image]

Now, on the script I have  `"D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\web.config"` which is the path I get when I call 
`Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());` from the server via a rest api.

But when I run it on the powershell I get **not file found** error.
[image]

how to access Azure .net core webiste files using powershell from my azure deploy pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `kudu` interface () for both deploying your application and making further changes (for more information looks here: [Kudu-Introduction](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/08/30/interacting-with-azure-web-apps-virtual-file-system-using-powershell-and-the-kudu-api/) / [Kudu-Wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki)).

Here is a link to discussion about similar topic: [Powershell-App-Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160812/running-azure-powershell-script-on-web-app-during-release-task)

Answer (score 1):

The script you're running runs **on the build agent**, not in your Azure service. The path `D:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config` is incorrect at that point. In fact, since your app service is zipped up, using this approach you'd have to unzip it, modify the config file, and rezip it before uploading it.

You shouldn't do that. The Deploy App Service task has built-in capabilities for transforming the configuration file at deployment time. Refer to the the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=vsts).

An even better approach is to use the app service app settings; define your configuration on the app service itself as opposed to relying on a web.config.