# Running azure powershell script on web app during release task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I have an 'azure powershell task' running in my VSTS release after my 'deploy to azure site' task.  In the powershell script, i have some transformations that i need to run on several of the files on the website, all based on the deployments variables.

The problem is I can't find the directory for the website.  The root directory that the task is run under is something like:

> D:\a_tasks\AzurePowerShell_71a1931a-effb-3d2e-8fd8-f7472a07cb62\3.1.18\

how do i point it to the d:\home\site\wwwroot\ , is there a build/release variable that automatically picks the deployment site location?  Or can i just write out 'd:\home\site\wwwroot\' and expect that to not change in the future?

Answer (score 1):

thats not how it works (if I got you right). your script will run on your build\release agent, not on the webapp. You would need to use native kudu capability to achieve what you want to achieve: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script

Comment: is there any way to include the kudu script in an azure release task? to have it read from my library variables inside the release?  I'm not seeing any real easy way for them to play with each other

Comment: you could use the post deployment script action of the `Azure App Service Deploy` task in Azure Devops and use inline\script from file and pass parameters to it, i think

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `kudu` interface for both **deploying the site** and **making transformations**.

You could keep the code of both actions in your `PowerShell` scripts. As a result, You will gain a lot of freedom in customization and boost extendability. It would be best if you attach them as build artifact / or repository reference.

If you add your `automation scripts` as a `package` you will  bound version of deployment scripts with each release. It enables backwards compatibility (between deployment code - application code).

[Pipeline definition example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IG2T.png)